# SenchaTouch Lock screen so it does not go into Landscape?

Tags: sencha-touch, landscape

Can someone point me to how this is done with SenchaTouch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is on an iOS device you cannot lock the orientation in Safari mobile.

If you are installing it as a web view/hybrid/native app (say with PhoneGap), you can lock the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(Ext.os.is.Android || Ext.os.is.iOS ){
            navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
        }
```

Using Phonegap u can do this.